# Using non homeland driver's license and IDP in Japan

Tags: japan, driving-licenses

So I am a US Citizen, I have been living in Hong Kong now for 5 years.  Being as I have no residence in the US, my license in the US has expired.  I have been maintaining my license in Hong Kong, which I converted through Hong Kong's license exchange program.

Soon I will be moving to Japan, and I'm having a lot of difficulty deciphering what I can and can't do.  Many references I am reading keep referring to the license as your "homeland"/"home country" license and IDP to determine validity.  So essentially, would a license I obtained in Hong Kong, and an IDP I obtained in Hong Kong, despite not being a Hong Kong citizen, entitle me to being able to drive in Japan, and allow me to skip the training license and get a full license through the conversion program and test?

Answer (score 2):

> would a license I obtained in Hong Kong, and an IDP I obtained in Hong Kong, despite not being a Hong Kong citizen, entitle me to being able to drive in Japan

Yes. (I'm in a similar situation; French citizen, US residence, US driving license + IDP, and had no issue to obtain the IDP with my US driving license via AAA and use it outside the US)

> allow me to skip the training license and get a full license through the conversion program and test?

Some countries limit for how long one can drive without a local driving license. The max time for Japan is [1 year](https://www.japancampers.com/international-driving-permit.html) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201018174443/https://www.japancampers.com/international-driving-permit.html)).

---

Regarding the Geneva conventions, see https://kart.st/en/drivers-license/hong-kong.html ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201018174611/https://kart.st/en/drivers-license/hong-kong.html)):

> Japan is only affiliated with the 1949 Geneva Convention, and Hong
> Kong is also affiliated with the 1949 Geneva Convention.
>
> Therefore, if Hong Kong issues a international driving permit (IDP)
> under the 1949 Geneva Convention in the proper format, it is valid to
> drive in Japan.
>
> An international driving permit (IDP) which is not under the 1949
> Geneva Convention in the proper format is not valid in Japan. Please
> confirm the international driving permit (IDP) is under the 1949
> Geneva Convention in the proper format.

Comment: Japan is 1 year max, I believe. The US embassy website has some info about it, although it does seem to shed a bit of a confusing light on it: https://jp.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/local-resources-of-u-s-citizens/driving-in-japan/

Comment: Also Hong Kong IDP is valid only if it's issued based on 1949 Geneva Convention. Any other is not valid for any period of time.